# How works std::condition_variable::wait_until

Tags: c++, condition-variable

Why this code works very fast?

```
int main() {
    std::condition_variable cv;
    std::mutex mtx;
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mtx);
    cv.wait_until(lock, std::chrono::system_clock::now() + 10000ms);

    return 0;
}
```

Seems like wait_until ignored

Comment: I'm shocked, even by now, there are not too much discussions about this serious problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're probably getting a [spurious wakeup](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait_until).  Try using the overload that accepts a predicate...

```
#include <condition_variable>

int main() {
    std::condition_variable cv;
    std::mutex mtx;
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mtx);
    cv.wait_until(lock, std::chrono::system_clock::now() + 10000ms, []{ return false; });

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I tried to illustrate that in a [**demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5c82f9d5bc6a135f) but I failed to achieve a spurious wakeup (in the two or three test-runs I did). Though I agree with your conclusion a spurious wakeup is nothing you can rely on. ;-)

Comment: @Scheff Yeah.  They're a bit like buses: wait ages for one and then dozens turn up at the same time :-)